# Euro Currency Format (Django)

Tags: django, variables, casting

I have a variable and am trying to format it to following format "100.000,00".

I have an amount (integer) and a price (decimal) and try to multiply these things to one total price with:

```
totalprice = price * decimal(amount)
```

I'm using Django and in the end I have to cast it to a string so I can use it in a text field.

Comment: formatting of the output was wrong, fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

I used a module which is named "Babel". You can import predefined formats there.

https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/api/numbers.html